# Is it possible to make the lines move diagonally in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In this program below, I can move the lines left and right, up and down. However, is it possible to make the lines move diagonally? E.g., when the up arrow and right arrow are pressed simultaneously the program makes a diagonal line moving NE?

```
from tkinter import *


canvas_height = 400
canvas_width = 600
canvas_colour = "orange"
p1_x = canvas_width / 2
p1_y = canvas_height
p1_colour = "black"
line_width = 10
line_length = 10


def p1_move_N(event):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y - line_length),
                       width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length


def p1_move_S(event):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, p1_y + line_length,
                       width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y + line_length


def p1_move_E(event):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x + line_length, p1_y,
                       width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length


def p1_move_W(event):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x - line_length, p1_y,
                       width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x - line_length


def erase_all(event):
    canvas.delete(ALL)

window = Tk()
window.title("Drawing Software")
canvas = Canvas(bg=canvas_colour, height=canvas_height,
                width=canvas_width, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

window.bind("<Up>", p1_move_N)
window.bind("<Down>", p1_move_S)
window.bind("<Left>", p1_move_W)
window.bind("<Right>", p1_move_E)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "moving diagonally"? If you press for example left and upper arrow at the same time, it should draw a pseudo diagonal line to the upper left corner...the problem is the size of the squares, which do not make it seem like a perfect line...

Comment: @Xenomorph the problem with trying to do 2 inputs at the same time is that the way this is configured, it can only handle one input at a time...

Comment: I would rather suggest using the numeric pad and bind 9 to NE, 3 to SE and so on.

Comment: Thank you @EricLevieil, do you know what code could acheive this outcome, im having trouble coming up with the right code to move diagnally

Comment: @JamesCorteen Have you tried simply binding for example both `p1_move_N` and `p1_move_W` to `7`? (Note that you need to add `add=True` to you bind to bind multiple functions to the same key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add functions like this one:

```
def p1_move_NE(event):
    global p1_y,p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x + line_length, (p1_y - line_length),
                   width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length
```

Then bind it with:

```
window.bind("9", p1_move_NE)
```

My other advices for your program will be to use classes and generic functions like that:

```
def p1_move(dx, dy):
    global p1
    canvas.create_line(p1[0], p1[1], p1[0] + dx, p1[1] + dy,
                   width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1 = (p1[0] + dx, p1[1] + dy)
```

(I used a tuple p1 in my example but a class Point will be still better.)